# Error when trying to compile es6 code to es5 using babel-cli

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-cli

I'm getting an error saying "*unexpected token export*" when trying to compile some es6 code using "*babel-cli*" with the presets "*es2015*" and "*stage-2*". I'm trying to export a function from the "*test.js*" file and import it in the "*index.js*" file but for some reason it doesn't accept "*export*" in "*test.js*".

Each module is installed locally, so I run it from the package.json "scripts" using "build: babel server/index.js -o server/index.babel.js".

My "*.babelrc*" file consists of:

```
 {
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"]
 }
```

test.js:

```
const test = (msg) => {
    console.log(msg)
};

export default test;
```

index.js:

index.js:

```
import test from './test'

test("Hello")
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you babelify `test.js` ?

Comment: What do you mean by babelify?

Comment: babelify is converting es6 to es5 using babel. i see you doing it for `index.js` in "scripts build:". you also need to do the same for `test.js`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, and the fact that you're getting that error means that it is reading the files properly. Make sure that you downloaded `stage-2` correctly, but I think your error is in that `export default` is still in `stage-1`.

Run `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-stage-1` and add `stage-1` to your presets.

That should do it. Here's a link to https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from and https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-ns-from